# Javascript - Inserting Image Text and description in a container

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
        <div id="CollectionALL">
            <div id="collection1" class="col">
                <img id="Img1" class="imageCS"/>
                <H1 id="Title1"></H1>
                <p id="Text1"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="collection2" class="col">
                <img id="Img2" class="imageCS"/>
                <H1 id="Title2"></H1>
                <p id="Text2"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hi all,

I'm just starting out on javascript and would like to check how i should go about replacing or inserting an image into each of the Img1, Img2 and Img3 tags.

I believe once i'm able to figure out the image, the title and texts should be in the same method?

```
function displayResult()
{
    var collect1=document.getElementById("img1").rows[0];
    var x=collect1.insertCell(-1);
    x.innerHTML="<img src='img/abc.png' alt='collection1'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the selectors for h1, p, img inner your container. then you can use setAttribute and innerHTML function to set content.

Then you can wrapped inside a loop and iterate the result array. The example below will shows you how it works inside the loop.

**like that**

```js
function displayResult()
{
    var collect = document.getElementById("collection1");
 
    let img = collect.querySelector('img');
    let h1 = collect.querySelector('h1');
    let p = collect.querySelector('p');
    img.setAttribute('src', "https://via.placeholder.com/100");
    h1.innerHTML = "collection1";
    p.innerHTML = "some text"
  
}

displayResult()
```

```html
        <div id="CollectionALL">
            <div id="collection1" class="col">
                <img id="Img1" class="imageCS"/>
                <H1 id="Title1"></H1>
                <p id="Text1"></p>
            </div>
            <div id="collection2" class="col">
                <img id="Img2" class="imageCS"/>
                <H1 id="Title2"></H1>
                <p id="Text2"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Instead of using Queryselector, 
Am i able to just use getElementById to replace each of the ID?
like 
Img1, Title 1 and Text 1 and eventually
Img2, Title 2 and Text 2?

I have an bunch of different images, Title and Text that i would like to just insert into the div

Comment: For that you need to put an id in each element that want, with queryselector you are taking all the elements, for example all the img's, not specifying. So, yes, you can do it, it's more work, but if it's what you want, do it.

Comment: @mc.python I only partially agree with you. You can do your approach but you can only give an id to the container. Then you can search with the querySelector within the container x for the tag name and make the modification. is a matter of taste. i would choose this way. is more generalistic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if I understood your question correctly, but if I did I see no use for JS to be used in here. Simply insert your src, title and text through the HTML.

```
        <div id="CollectionALL">
        <div id="collection1" class="col">
            <img id="Img1" class="imageCS" src="img/abc.png">
            <h1 id="Title1">My Title</h1>
            <p id="Text1">My Text</p>
        </div>
        <div id="collection2" class="col">
            <img id="Img2" class="imageCS" src="img/abc.png>
            <h1 id="Title2">My Title</h1>
            <p id="Text2">My Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

note that "img" is not a tag with a closing, thus ending it with a />:

> ```
>             <img id="Img2" class="imageCS"/>
> ```

is not quite right. Also, tags in HTML are case-sensitive, and so "H1" is not a valid tag, but "h1" is.

Comment: I'm working with an html file with an external Javascript and I'm trying to learn how to replace and insert images, text using the id without having to do it in html.

I understand it would be much easier to do that in just HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ImgA= document.getElementById("Img1");
Img1.src = "abc.jpg";
var TitleA= document.getElementById("Title1");
TitleA.textContent = "Some Title Header Thing";
var TextA= document.getElementById("Text1");
TextA.textContent = "qwerty some text";
```

I think i'll be doing it this way.
Seems to work
Thanks to everyone